# Is there any way to see the group_vars, host_vars, etc. available to a host in ansible?

Tags: configuration, ansible, configuration-management, ansible-playbook

So I just started a new company, and while familiarizing myself with the ansible repository, I was wondering if there's any way to see the variables that come from group_vars, host_vars and all that together in one place, it's non-trivial to gather all the facts about a host. For example if I have a hosts file like

```
[foo:children]
bar

[bar]
baz
```

and so I have two group_vars files
foo.yml

```
---
app: kyle
```

and
bar.yml

```
---
env: prod
```

and then I have a host_vars file baz.yml

```
---
type: app-server
```

is there any way to get an out put like the following:

```
Host: baz
app = kyle
env = prod
type = app-server
```

I've looked into the setup module, but when I run the equivalent of `ansible all -m setup` it returns all of the `ansible_*` variables but none of my defined variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found an answer, from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208819/list-all-ansible-variables-for-a-host-or-group-with-an-ad-hoc-command).

`ansible all -m debug -a "var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]"`